# Thread UI sleep withtout freezing scrollview

Tags: android

I'm trying to implements a game AI, and I got the following problem :
I'm calling a method from another class my UI Activity class, this method call itself some methods of the UI Activity class (to simulate click on screen among other things), and the things is, at the end of this method, I need to "pause"  the game a few seconds to let the user see what did the AI.

So I tried running the method in another thread, but I got the error message providing from editing a widget from another thread. I tried to sleep the UI thread, but by doing that, the user can't use the scrollview anymore, and the changes aren't display before the sleep but after.

So I'd like to know how can I do this ? 
(I've read some topics about AsyncTask, Handler, but can't make it work the way I need)
Thank's

Comment: Can't you just simulate a pause without actually pausing the thread. I mean, inactivate click/touch listeners and stop moving objects and whatnot. Seems safer.

Comment: Can't do that, the user must be able to use the UI during the pause

Comment: Well in fact, I'll try to simulate it by using a timer

Comment: You're more familiar with this than I am, so I guess your approach is good :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need runOnUiThread.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

http://steve.odyfamily.com/?p=12

Comment: I'll try with this, it should work thank's, keep you posted
edit: with the timer, maybe I won't need another thread at all

Comment: It works just fine, thank's ! I use the timer to simulate the click after a few secs and use runOnUiThread to simulate the click in the UI thread. Thank's !